# Read a Map from properties file through applicationContext.xml in spring

Tags: spring, dictionary, collections, properties, applicationcontext

I have a map in my properties file as below:

```
property1=Hello_1
property2=Hello_2
list={a:'A', b:'B', c:'C'}
```

and I have a model object that contains:

```
public class Model {

    String s1;
    String s2;
    Map<String, String> map;
}
```

and I want to read it from applicationContext.xml and fill it in my java Map like below:

```
<bean id="model" class="Model">
    <property name="s1" value="${property1}" />
    <property name="s2" value="${property2}" />
    <property name="map" value="${list}" />
</bean>
```

I can read `s1` and `s2` successfully and fill it in the model, but I don't know how to fill the `map` collection, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Spring expression to handle that. Try `<property name="map" value="#{${list}}" />`